# Send push notification by using Parse from laravel web server to android device

Tags: laravel, parse-platform, push-notification

I cant find how to send push notification by using Parse.com from my web server to android device using laravel. can anybody help me ?

Comment: https://parse.com/docs ? - there is a PHP section there, perhaps that can get you started if you're using laravel: https://parse.com/docs/php/guide

Comment: You've also got a package too: https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this documentation: 
https://parse.com/docs/php/guide#push-notifications

and to this GitHub project:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk

This PHP Lib can be included to your laravel project

Push:

```
ParseClient::initialize( $app_id, $rest_key, $master_key );
$data = array("alert" => "Hi!");

// Push to Channels
ParsePush::send(array(
"channels" => ["PHPFans"],
"data" => $data));

// Push to Query
$query = ParseInstallation::query();
$query->equalTo("design", "rad");

ParsePush::send(array(
"where" => $query,
"data" => $data));
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to delegate the Parse itself to send your push notification instead of using your web server (more secure). So, you can manage this delegation via writing a cloud function in Parse backend, and call this cloud function from your web server. From links in comment section of post, you can call the cloud function via the Php SDK of Parse;

```
$results = ParseCloud::run("aCloudFunction", array("from" => "php"));
```

In cloud function, you have to query the installation table and find the user and send your push.Hope this helps.

Regards.